# Are creating websites for backlink blackhat?

Tags: seo, backlinks, blackhat

**The problem**

I have been looking for a reputable company to help a client of mine generate some backlinks.

Now I thought everyone these days would try and talk us into **good content** and **competitions** our **users want to share**. Which is **great**, I just needed someone to do run that.

But I've found that companies are offering a different strategy in the form of:

Creating 100's of average quality websites within the target niche then linking them back to the core site.

Using claims of "we have never been caught because we are careful with what websites we create and the rate we create them"

I'm fighting that this is a bad idea.. But the client also knows I'm a total hippy when it comes to "keeping Google happy  and best practises" in everything I do... and in business sometimes you get a little dirty.

**My points has been as follows:**

"Looking at this from Googles point of view, if they are seeing this strategy taking off they will target it.. As they do not want 200 “backlink websites” per 1 site in their search results.  "

**Why here?**

The reason to post this here is i'm sturggling to find any good information on this exact strategy.. Lots about old "just getting as many links as you can.."

Also lots of things on "Getting good quality links natrally"

But not much on "Setting up 100's of 25-40 page rank sites in your niche just to target you with good quality links"

**What I need**

Does anyone have any good words or articles about this exact strategy and why it isn't viable in the long term?

Or am I being a hippy and this is just the "new thing"??

Comment: Not worth the effort. Those site will rank poorly and carry no weight so links from them will carry no weight. And if Google finds out about your scheme then your site gets the banhammer and you're done. So, yeah, bad idea. (and yes, this is black hat).

Comment: But their point is they create sites and get their page ranks up to a reasonable rate before they link to you... I agree it's a bad idea.. But they have the base covered in the "links from relevant high quality sources"

Comment: Now they've got 40 times the work when they could have been dedicating all of that time, effort, and cost on promoting the main site. Still a bad idea.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea. The difficulty is how easy it is for a client to get sucked up into the "get you to number one on Google" especially a client who is pretty clued up on SEO. But when someone is saying they have the "secret formula" that Google won't find out with compelling examples I really need to find an article targeted at it specifically to prove a point.

I also pointed out that they would own the links so if we break with them they will just take them sites down anyways, but they are still fighting how great they are.

Comment: This is nothing more then yet another link scheme. Just look for articles about Penguin, JC Penney, or anyone else who got creamed because they build links unnaturally. A link scheme is a link scheme and Google is coming down hard on anyone caught doing one. No matter how smart they think they are, Google got a whole team of people who are smarter. Let them do it and learn their lesson the hard way.

Comment: @James - Permanent ban and 6 months to bankruptcy for one of our competitors. If you think you can handle this, its your judgement call. And no, Bing didn't do them a bit of good.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I hear what you are saying.. Thought isn't that a bit extreme? We did get hit with the ban hammer for a day back in the day.. But we just said it was a seo mistake and we was back up number one the next day, we just dropped from that day onwards as we stopped any backlinking strategies.. 

I see a lot of people saying how they was banned for ever.. But Google need you to be there if you're popular just as much as you do. If people go looking for you surely you have to be there or people will just think Google is broken?

Just to clarify I am saying that this is a BAD IDEA!

Comment: Whatever they did was so egregious that they never came back. There was only one link that Google would allow and that was if you directly searched for the company name. Obviously Google thought it was worth more than a wrist slap. Don't be overconfident, Google doesn't really need you. There are 100,000 to take your place who will play by the rules.

Comment: +1 For entertaining use of the word "hippy", and drawing attention to a subject that others should be aware of.

Comment: I can see two of my competitors have less than ten domains supplying over 5000 backlinks in total. They've been doing it for two years unnoticed.
I won't be tempted, but I wish google would actively police their search system, as well as improving the algorhytm to detect these cheats.

Answer (score 1):

> reating 100's of average quality websites within the target niche then linking them back to the core site.

This strategy is very old and some time ago (even 2 years ago) it gives great results. Google likes target niche sites and backlinks from them are valuable.

But all the essence of this strategy is in quality of backlinks, quantity of them and in the speed of their growing.

2-3 sites with 5-10 links will help you, but 200-300 will carry the penalty to you.